# How to include external ASP file?

Tags: database, asp-classic, connection

I have a "Main" SQL database - with 20 websites sending / receving data.

All sites Works with Classic ASP.

Today I create an include file to connect all sites to db.

My question is:

Its possible to create only one "conn file" and include this file to all sites?

Why?

because I need to change the connection - and now I need to change 20 files for all sites..

any idea?

Comment: Are the websites all on the same server?

Comment: Make sure you have Server Side Includes enabled, also.

Comment: @Paul - I think Classic ASP supports server side include syntax by default, if Classic ASP is enabled you don't have to do anything else.  You have to enable SSI on Apache but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: @John - Server 2012 it has to be enabled depending on the server build.

Comment: @Paul That is true, it's very easy to miss the check-box when adding the role to a Server 2012 server.

Answer (score 3):

Place that file to include in a folder on the server.

Create a virtual directory in each site pointing to that folder.

Add the following to the either the pages that need the connection or a global include file for each site.

```
<!--#include virtual="/virtualdir/connfilename"-->
```